# WordPress: generate new post by adding new category

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, custom-taxonomy

I have costom post type (a-posts) and custom hierarchical taxonomy (a-tax). Now, question: is it possible automatically generate new custom post when user add new custom category. Im searching for some hooks last two days but can't find anything...
So, this is my variante for functions.php:

```
add_action('a-tax_term_register', 'newpost');
function newpost ($a-tax-name) {
     $my_post = array(
         'post_title' => $a-tax-name
      );
    wp_insert_post($mypost);
}
```

Or maybe it is better to add `wp_insert_post()` in function which create new taxonomy term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add any custom function to any standart functions by using wp hooks. In this situation you need to use somethink like:

```
    add_action('create_a-tax', 'new_post');
    function newpost () {
    wp_insert_post($postargs);
    }
```